# Why doAnswer() stubs are not reset?

Tags: java, mockito

I have 2 tests which call the same code but check different things.
The first one uses `doAnswer()` to stub a method call and put parameters checker.
The second one doesn't need it.

But when I run my tests, the second test fails because fails the checker that was injected in the first test. And if I run only the second test it passes.

So, should I reset `doAnswer()` stub with empty checker im my `setUp()` method? Why so?

This is a checker that I use in the first test:

```
    final Map<String, String> expectedParams = new HashMap<>();
    expectedParams.put("param1", "A");
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            String name = (String) args[0];
            Assert.assertEquals("event1", name);
            Map<String, String> params = (Map<String, String>) args[1];
            Assert.assertEquals(expectedParams, params);
            return null;
        }}).when(mMyMockedObject).myTestedMethod(anyString(), anyMap());
```

and this is the beginning

```
@Mock
MyMockedClass mMyMockedObject;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("setUp()");
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);        
}
```

In the second test I **never** call doAnswer() but my checker is called I don't know why :(

---

Adding the whole test.

```
@RunWith(LocalRobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
public class MyTest {
    private static final String MAIN = "main";

    @Mock
    MyMockedClass mMyMockedObject;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setUp()");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // this will connect MAIN with mMyMockedObject
        SomClassICantShareNda.someMethodNda(MAIN, mMyMockedObject);        
    }
```

Hey, this is where I understand that this is my fault, not Mockito.
This is where I add new mMyMockedObject but forget to erase old instance of mMyMockedObject (inside SomClassICantShareNda, in static collection). So, after each test new mMyMockedObject will be created and added to collection.

Comment: could you provide the whole test?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that was my fault.
The code duplicated many mocked object, cached them in a static collection and didn't reset it in setUp()